# throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')

Tags: javascript, postgresql

There was a problem, I don’t know how to fix it, everything seems to be connected normally, but the error doesn’t disappear in any way, it tries to connect js to the postgresql database, but it throws this error `throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE : client password must be a string') ^ Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string`

Below I get a code in which connection data is found, if something is missing, then tell me, thank you very much in advance, I have been suffering from this problem for a long time.

settings.json

```
{
"sqltools.connections": [
    {
        "previewLimit": 50,
        "server": "localhost",
        "port": 5432,
        "driver": "PostgreSQL",
        "name": "database",
        "password": "5432",
        "username": "postgres",
        "database": "postgres"
    }
]
}
```

db.js

```
const configs = {
host: 'localhost',
port: 5432,
user: 'postgres',
password: '5432',
database: 'postgres'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another name for your DB? Using postgres might be as issue because that's more like a reserved for word for the DB. However, this error majorly comes from password. Confirm your DB password is not empty.